# Multiselect by SHIFT key in Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, multipleselection

I'm using Angular CDK/Material table. Is there any way how to select more rows by pressing SHIFT key and click, for example like in Windows explorer?
(So I click on first row, then press SHIFT key and then click on the 10th record = first 10 records are selected)
Here is an example in JS that I have found, I'm expecting something like this:

codepen.io/edsinek/pen/ezJWGz

Thank you!